# Assembly.LoadFrom using md5 hash not working

Tags: .net, reflection, powershell, powershell-2.0

My Assembly.LoadFrom(path, hashValue, hashAlgorithm) is not working, failing with a "located assembly does not match assembly reference" exception.

This is in powershell 2.

I have determined the hash value by first loading the assembly using Load(bytes) which works fine.  Using that result, I access the MD5 hash value from the evidence, as follows:

```
$a= [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)  
$h=$a.Evidence|? {$_ -is [System.Security.Policy.Hash]}  
$md5= $h.MD5
```

I bring the hash value into another powershell session, so I have a clean AppDomain, and attempt this:

```
$md5=[byte[]] (values that I determined)  
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("pathToMyAssembly", $md5, "MD5")
```

that's what fails.   Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried the equivalent in c#, still fails.  Perhaps evidence.MD5 is not the hash value that is needed by LoadFrom?

Answer (score 1):

The `LoadFrom` method you are calling is only available from .NET 4 onwards. Seeing Powershell still runs on .NET 3.5, calling this wont work.

Perhaps you can just pass `null` to the 2nd parameter. EG:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("pathToMyAssembly", null, $md5, "MD5")
```

[According to MSDN, the above method is now obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8c4tzhc.aspx), but for 3.5 you have no other choice :)

Comment: I tweaked the registry so that PS runs using the .Net 4 CLR.  I also tested with a compiled c# app.  No go.